# How to get first 3 lines of a file and then everything else

Tags: php

I have a txt file like so:

> This is line 1.
>
> This is line 2.
>
> This is line 3.
>
> This is the rest.
>
> Lorem and so on.

I want to use PHP to get the first three lines into a $variable, and then get everything else in the document into a $variable.

I've had some degree of success with this:

```
<?php

$file = fopen("text.txt","r");
$count = "0";

while(! feof($file))
  {
  $count++;

  if ($count=="1") {
  $line1 = fgets($file);
  }

  if ($count=="2") {
  $line2 = fgets($file);
  }

  if ($count=="3") {
  $line3 = fgets($file);
  }

//everything else?

}

echo $line1;
echo $line2;
echo $line3;
//echo $everythingelse;

fclose($file);

?>
```

The following works:

```
echo fgets($file);
```

But this doesn't:

```
$line1 = fgets($file);
```

So, A) what am I doing wrong with that, and B) how do I get the rest of the file, and C) is there a better way to implement this? I feel like my way is clumsy and someone'll suggest something obvious which can do all this.

Thanks guys!

Comment: you could use cURL and then split the result finding "\n" and you get an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A)** Your code is fine until the end of the if: you can't simply assign the value returned from `fgets` to a variable within a `while`, because the loop will overwrite it next time, with the content of the next line and so on, until it have reached the last line, which is somehow always empty. When you directly print the output of `fgets`, the `while` will echo one line by one as it proceeds in the loop.

**B)** You code just runs fine with this small correction: use the *concatenating assignment operator* to append the line to the variable instead of overwriting it. ([String Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php))

```
<?php

$file = fopen("text.txt","r");
$count = "0";

while(!feof($file)) {
  $count++;    
    switch ($count) {
        case "1":
            $line1 = fgets($file);
            break;
        case "2":
            $line2 = fgets($file);
            break;
        case "3":
            $line3 = fgets($file);
            break;
        default: 
            $everythingelse .= fgets($file);
    }
}

echo $everythingelse;

fclose($file);

echo "\n\n\n\n\n\n";
echo "Plus, here is line one: ".$line1."\n";
echo "This is line three: ".$line3."\n";
echo "And finally, line two: ".$line2."\n";
```

(I also replaced your if with a switch, which does the same)

An example output:
[image: Output screenshot]

**C)** I think that your method fixed it's fine for your purpose, specially if you already getting the file contents through fgets (and thus using a while). This method is native to work inside a while like yours. Of course you can also do as suggested by Kolink and Michael, using `implode`, which may even be faster.

Answer (score 4):

This is easiest with [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) which reads an entire file into an array of lines.  You can then use array operations like [`array_splice()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) to remove the first three and return them, then join them back into strings with `\n`.

```
// Reads the file into an array
$lines = file($file);

// Cuts off everything after the first three
$the_rest = array_splice($lines, 3);
// leaving the first three in the original array $lines
$first_three = $lines;

// Stick them back together as strings by implode() with newlines
$first_three = implode("\n", $first_three);
$the_rest = implode("\n", $the_rest);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
$data = file("text.txt");
$beginning = implode(PHP_EOL,array_splice($data,0,3));
$end = implode(PHP_EOL,$data);
```

Used functions: [`file`](http://php.net/file), [`implode`](http://php.net/implode), [`array_splice`](http://php.net/array-splice) and [`PHP_EOL` constant](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-eol).